# Forcing property substitution before execution of maven versions:resolve-ranges

Tags: maven

We have a set of libraries that we want to roll major versions of in sync, but will have minor versions that "float" independently, in between the major version changes. To represent these as dependencies in a pom we're using a custom property.  Our pom looks something like this:

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>our-thing</artifactId>
  ...
  <properties>
    <shared.version>[1.4,1.5)</shared.version>
  </properties>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-foo</artifactId>
      <version>${shared.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-bar</artifactId>
      <version>${shared.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-baz</artifactId>
      <version>${shared.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
<project>
```

Let's say that the actual versions of these libraries are

- `library-foo`: 1.4.1
- `library-bar`: 1.4.3
- `library-baz`: 1.4.5

Now, we have a build script that uses [versions:resolve-ranges](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/resolve-ranges-mojo.html) to replace range versions with their actual current versions.  (We do this to create a version of the pom with all the dependencies "pinned", for rollback purposes.) Unfortunately, the behavior of resolve-ranges is to look at all the dependencies which use the property `shared.version`, determine what the highest common version is, and then substitute that in the **property**.  So the output looks like this:

```
<project ...>
  ...
  <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>our-thing</artifactId>
  ...
  <properties>
    <shared.version>1.4.1</shared.version>
  </properties>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-foo</artifactId>
      <version>${shared.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  ...
```

Apparently this is following the behavior described for the [update-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html) mojo?  Anyway, this does not get us what we want obviously, as it ends up building with old versions for two of the libraries.

What we want is to put the actual current versions of each dependency in there and leave the property alone.  (Or change the property, I don't really care, it becomes irrelevant if the dependency versions were changed.)  So we want output like the following:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-foo</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-bar</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.our.stuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>library-baz</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

I cannot figure out a way to get the versions plugin to do this. One way to solve this, it would seem, is to force the property substitution on `shared.version` before running the pom through resolve-ranges.  But I cannot find a plugin or other way to force the substitution.  Does anyone know of a way to do that, or other ideas for getting the output we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found that the [maven replacer plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) can be used to manually force the substitution of the `shared.version` property before running resolve-ranges.  I just call it in our script (after using mvn help:evaluate to verify that the pom in question has `shared.version`).

It still seems a bit clunky to me, and requires adding the configuration below to every pom that uses `shared.version`.  It sure would be nice if there was a way to get this behavior in replace-ranges itself, or at least a plugin that just does property substitution directly instead of using what is essentially a global search and replace in the file.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <file>pom.xml</file>
      <regex>true</regex>
      <token>\$\{shared\.version\}</token>
      <value>${shared.version}</value>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```